# JavaScript insert createElement till parent element is "full"

Tags: javascript, html, css, createelement

I've some wrapping element on my HTML page which has a relative width and height setting, to cover all of the available screen.

```html
<body onload="init()">
    <div id="wrapper" class="choicebox" style="width:100%;height:100%;border:1px solid black">
    </div>
</body>
```

Next, I have Java Script which fills a fixed amount of new elements (SPAN boxes) in the wrapping DIV:

```js
function init() {

        for (let i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
        insertBox("X")
        }
    }


function insertBox(currentValue, index, arr){
    var new_element = document.createElement('span')
    new_element.id = currentValue
    new_element.innerHTML = currentValue;
    new_element.classList.add('box');
    document.getElementById('wrapper').appendChild(new_element)
}
```

The CSS definition is the following:

```css
.box {
    background: #8b95f1;
    padding: 20px;
    font-size:1.0em;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

This code is working. However, how can I create exactly the amount of necessary SPAN boxes inside the wrapping DIV till it is "full" (more elements inserted are not visible anymore without scrolling)?

Thanks for any hint.

Comment: Thinking you could set dims on your box and calculate the number of boxes that will fit in the current window using the screensize/window size. (Maybe something from here: https://andylangton.co.uk/blog/development/get-viewportwindow-size-width-and-height-javascript)

Comment: What does "full" even mean? As soon as I resize my browser window, the number of spans that "fill" the wrapper changes. What then? What are you trying to build/achieve here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another answer, much simpler

Here I compare scrollHeight and offsetHeight, offsetHeight is the display height, scrollHeight is the actual overflow height, when offsetHeight >= scrollHeight, the wrapper is not filled

```js
let wrapper = document.querySelector('#wrapper');

function init() {
  while (wrapper.scrollHeight < wrapper.offsetHeight) {
    insertBox("X");
  }
  wrapper.removeChild(wrapper.lastChild);
}


function insertBox(currentValue, index, arr) {
  var new_element = document.createElement('span')
  new_element.id = currentValue
  new_element.innerHTML = currentValue;
  new_element.classList.add('box');
  wrapper.appendChild(new_element)
}
```

```css
.box {
  background: #8b95f1;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 1.0em;
  display: inline-block;
}

#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow: visible;
}
```

```html
<body onload="init()">
  <div id="wrapper" class="choicebox" style="">
  </div>
</body>
```

I modified some css to make the wrapper have a max height

Comment: Thank you for the great answer! It is exactly what I've searched for!

Answer (score 0):

Do mean something like this? I'm expecting that all boxes will always have the same sizing. I also added the event `onresize` in case of the window is changing it's size.

```js
function loadboxes() {
    insertBox("X");
    var box = document.getElementById('X');
    var boxWidth = box.offsetWidth;
    var boxHeight = box.offsetHeight;

    var wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');
    var width = wrapper.offsetWidth;
    var height = wrapper.offsetHeight;
    wrapper.innerHTML = ''

    var maxAmountHorizontal = parseInt(width / boxWidth)
    var maxAmountVertical = parseInt(height / boxHeight)

    for (let i = 0; i < (maxAmountHorizontal * maxAmountVertical); i++)     {
        insertBox("X")
    }
 }


function insertBox(currentValue, index, arr) {
    var new_element = document.createElement('span')
    new_element.id = currentValue
    new_element.innerHTML = currentValue;
    new_element.classList.add('box');
    document.getElementById('wrapper').appendChild(new_element)
}
```

```css
.box {
    background: #8b95f1;
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 1.0em;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<body onload="loadboxes()" onresize="loadboxes()">
    <div id="wrapper" class="choicebox" style="width:100%;height:100%;border:1px solid black">
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I use `Element.getBoundingClientRect()` to calculate the max count of box

I append a temp box to the wrapper to calculate the size of box

```js
function calcCount(){
  let wrapperRect = document.querySelector('#wrapper').getBoundingClientRect();
  let temp = document.createElement('span');
  temp.innerText = 'X';
  temp.className = 'box';
  wrapper.appendChild(temp);
  let tempRect = temp.getBoundingClientRect();
  wrapper.removeChild(temp);
  
  return Math.floor(wrapperRect.width / tempRect.width) * Math.floor(wrapperRect.height / tempRect.height);
}
```

```js
//...
  let maxCount = calcCount();
  for (let i = 0; i < maxCount; i++) {
//...
```